# Ruby: why do while and until not return last line they execute from a function?

Tags: ruby

I expect a while loop to return the last statement it executes, but a function does not seem to return that.

**(1)** This seems to work..

```
[10] pry(main)> counter = 0
=> 0
[11] pry(main)> a = counter+=1 while counter < 10
=> nil
[12] pry(main)> a
=> 10
```

**(2)** This does not work as I expected. I expect 10 to be returned and stored into `b`.

```
[19] pry(main)> def increment(terminal_value)
[19] pry(main)*   counter = 0  
[19] pry(main)*   while counter < terminal_value
[19] pry(main)*     counter+=1
[19] pry(main)*   end  
[19] pry(main)* end  
=> :increment
[20] pry(main)> b = increment(10)
=> nil
[21] pry(main)> b
=> nil
```

**Questions:**

- Why, in **(1)**, does `nil` get returned from the assignment statement?
- Why does `b` not get assigned `10`?

**Update:**

As @DaveNewton mentioned, in **(1)**, I thought I was doing:

```
a = (counter +=1 while counter < 10)
```

but I was actually doing:

```
(a = counter +=1) while counter < 10
```

Comment: You're doing different things. *(1)* gets a `nil` and displays it, so does *(2)*. In *(1)* you're incrementing a local variable, `counter`, and displaying it. In *(2)* you set a local variable `b` to the return result of calling `increment`, which is `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both your examples, the `while` loop results as `nil`.

From [`while` loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop):

> The result of a `while` loop is `nil` unless `break` is used to supply a value.

The same for [`until`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop):

> Like a `while` loop the result of an `until` loop is `nil` unless `break` is used.

Comment: @KubaSub `a` has the value of the assignment `counter+=1`, not the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing Yu Hao's answer is the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064159/implicit-return-values-in-ruby) question which states

> Any statement in ruby returns the value of the last evaluated expression.

and following that logic if you change your code to (not saying this is good practice or condoning it, just an example):

```
def increment(terminal_value)
  counter = 0  
    while counter < terminal_value
      counter+=1
    end
  counter
end

b = increment(10)
```

It will output 10.