# Using Interactive Ruby program, Closes when I enter things

Tags: ruby

I followed an example for this to start learning Ruby. The following code works inside of my text editor (Visual Studio Code). But when I open the file using the interactive ruby program. It doesn't seem to work.

```
puts "Hello there! Please enter a number to square: "
number = gets.chomp.to_i

def squared(number)
        squared = number * number
        return squared.to_s
end

puts "Your number is: " + number.to_s
puts "Your number squared is: " + square(number)
```

It prints out the initial "Hello there! Please enter a number to square:"
But once I type a number and press enter, the program abruptly closes.

Comment: What command are you using to run it interactively?

Comment: Closes? How are you running it?

Comment: Well, I basically double clicked my example.rb file, it opened the command prompt and printed the "Please enter a number to square:" 

Sorry, I'm very new to Ruby.

Comment: When I'm using the text editor I use this: ruby .\example.rb.
Then it prints the question, I hit 2 or something, press enter, then it pushes out
the correct number for me.

But if it's running on the Interactive Ruby software I downloaded, it closes after the first attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're double-clicking the `example.rb` file, which opens in `cmd.exe` and then closes automatically when it is done executing `example.rb`. That is the normal behavior for Windows: `cmd.exe` closes automatically after running whatever application invoked it.

What you want to do instead is manually open a command prompt (`cmd.exe`) and then run your application with `ruby example.rb`. This will keep `cmd.exe` open after your application finishes running, because `cmd.exe` was not invoked by your application; it was invoked manually by you.

This will allow you to see the `Your number is:` output after your application has finished running. This output is still being printed when you double-click `example.rb`, but the window closes so quickly that you can't see it.

Additionally, your application has some errors in it. Specifically, you're attempting to call `square(number)` when you should be calling `squared(number)`.

Here is your code cleaned up a little bit:

```
puts 'Hello there! Please enter a number to square: '
number = gets.chomp.to_i

def squared(number)
  number * number
end

puts "Your number is: #{number}"
puts "Your number squared is: #{squared(number)}"
```

Note the use of single quotes for strings that do not include [string interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html), the [implicit return](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064324/3784008) for the `squared` method, and string interpolation for the `puts` calls.

Comment: Thank you! I should have tried that. I quickly figured out that I had to type out the whole file path as well. Is there a quicker way to navigate through the cmd.exe? I guess I could copy paste the file path...

Comment: I'll assume that your application is in `C:\Projects\example_app\example.rb` and that when you open `cmd.exe` you start in `C:\Windows\system32`. Run `cd \Projects\example_app`, then you can run `ruby example.rb`. If your app is on another drive then you have to switch to that drive first, e.g., `D:` then `cd \Projects\example_app`.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Not sure why the example included to_i and to_s. Never seen those before. This version makes more sense and has less obvious information such as the squared = number * number.

I appreciate your input.

Comment: Oh! The problem was that I had it in the D: drive. And I didn't exactly choose an easy to find path. My pathing was Multimedia\Documents\GitHub\Rubybook\example.rb

Comment: `to_i` is required because `gets` returns a string, and you need to coerce the string to an integer. That's what `to_i` does. `to_s` is used in your example because Ruby will not automatically coerce an integer to a string when called with `puts`, but string interpolation (description is linked above) will do that automatically. `puts 'foo' + 1.to_s` and `puts "foo#{1}"` are functionally equivalent, but "[the Ruby way](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#strings)" says to use string interpolation, not string concatenation, where possible.